# Remove duplicate datetime dates from list

Tags: python, datetime

I create a list of dates like so:

```
begin=dt.date(2010,1,1)
back=pd.date_range(end = begin, periods = 11).to_pydatetime().tolist()
forward=pd.date_range(start = begin, periods = 11).to_pydatetime().tolist()
```

I then append this list of dates to a new variable:

```
date_centered=[]
date_centered.append(back)
date_centered.append(forward)
date_centered
```

Output:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 22, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 23, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 24, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 25, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 26, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 27, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 28, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 29, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 30, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 31, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0)],
 [datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 2, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 3, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 4, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 5, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 6, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 7, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 8, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 9, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 10, 0, 0),
  datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 11, 0, 0)]]
```

I want to remove the duplicate date, in this case 2010,1,1. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python `set`s to get rid of the duplicate item :

```py
set_back = set(back)
set_forward = set(forward)
# updates `set_back` by removing elements from `set_forward`
set_back.difference_update(set_forward)
# convert `set_back` and `set_forward` back to lists
# and add them to your `date_centered` result
date_centered = [list(set_back), list(set_forward)]
```

However, given your first lines of code, maybe you just want to get rid of the extra date by removing it from the `back` list :

```py
begin = dt.date(2010,1,1)
back = pd.date_range(end = begin, periods = 11).to_pydatetime().tolist()
forward = pd.date_range(start = begin, periods = 11).to_pydatetime().tolist()

back.pop() # removes the last item

date_centered= [back, forward]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the set of both lists (this will get rid of duplicates within every list) and subtract the common elements of both sets (A and B) from all possible values (A or B). This will return only the unique elements.

```
list((set(back) | set(forward)) - (set(back) & set(forward)))
```